# Getting inaccurate results converting from New York State projection to NAD83 with Python's pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, united-states

I've been trying to do a standard coordinate translation between [New York State Long Island (ESRI:102718)](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/nad-1983-stateplane-new-york-long-island-fips-3104-feet/) and latitude/longitude ([EPSG:4269](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/))...but I keep getting the wrong lat/lng results.

I don't think this has anything to do with the [pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) library in particular, but maybe I'm missing something in the transformation process.

Sample data comes from NYC.gov: http://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-selfac.page

Its [documentation](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/pdf/bytes/selfac_datainfo.pdf) says:

> The X coordinate of the XY coordinate pair which depicts the approximate location of the facility, program, or parkland property. (Also see Y COORDINATE). Facilities' X and Y coordinates must be used together for mapping selection. **The XY coordinates are expressed in the New York Long Island State Plane coordinate system.**

Here's a sample record:

```

## Sample record:

"3861130100",1,"MN",104,"MANHATTAN COMMUNITY DISTRICT 4",731,1,"YAI - YOUNG ADULT INSTITUTE",
"460 W 34 St","10001",3807,7,72,,98,,,,91,57," 103","0103",3,2,10,5500,1007310001.000,
984533.000,213998.000,"L"
```

So, the python code:

`import pyproj
NYSP1983 = pyproj.Proj(init="ESRI:102718")
x, y = (984533, 213998)
NYSP1983(x, y, inverse=True)`

That inverse projection should result in the lat/lng coordinates. However, the result is nowhere near New York:

```
       (-65.75200831429146, 41.80318458470038)
```

According to [Google geocoder, these are the proper coordinates](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=460%20W%2034%20St,%20Manhattan,%20NY):

```
    location: {
        lat: 40.7541045,
        lng: -73.9989178
    }
```

Here's another way to do transformations in pyproj, going from latlng to the specified X/Y projection, but still no dice:

`import pyproj
NYSP1983 = pyproj.Proj(init="ESRI:102718")
lng, lat = (-73.9989178, 40.7541045)
NYSP1983(lng, lat)`

The result:

```
            (300091.3883012832, 65232.600609979076)
```

Doing an explicit transform between systems doesn't help either:

`import pyproj
NAD83 = pyproj.Proj(init="EPSG:4269")
NYSP1983 = pyproj.Proj(init="ESRI:102718")
x, y = (984533, 213998)
pyproj.transform(NYSP1983, NAD83, x, y)`

```
         (-65.75200831429146, 41.80318458470038)
```

What am I missing here?

### Edit

Seems that I'm missing some parameters that need to be set up, such as `False_Easting`...but I don't know how in pyproj (or in any system) how to specify that. Namely, how do I use what's in this PROJCS string (example here: https://gist.github.com/veltman/6be84d216376814cdc67) to initialize the desired projection?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was my reading of the documentation of the `pyproj.Proj()` constructor function. The `preserve_units` optional argument has to be set to `True`:

https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/40#issuecomment-165585816

```
NYSP1983 = pyproj.Proj(init="ESRI:102718", preserve_units=True)
x, y = (984533, 213998)
NYSP1983(x, y, inverse=True)
```

Output

```
   (-73.99897854592253, 40.75405155302713)
```

It turns out `pyproj.Proj()` will ignore the `+to_meter` param without the `preserve_units=True` being included as an argument. i.e., you have to do `preserve_units=True` in this situation:

```
projstr = '+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs'

myproj = pyproj.Proj(projstr, preserve_units=True)
myproj(x, y, inverse=True)
```